# Lipschitz type problem in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is analytic on a convex domain $D$ and $|f'(z)|\leq m$ for all $z \in D$.  Prove that $|f(z_2)-f(z_1)|\leq m|z_2-z_1|$.

Since the line segment containing $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in $D$, then by the FTC we have $|f(z_2)-f(z_1)|\leq|\int_{z_1}^{z_2}f'(z)\,dz|\leq m\int_{z_1}^{z_2}\,|dz|=m|z_2-z_1|.$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your proof is that there's not a general notion of an integral from $z_1$ to $z_2$ if $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence you have to integrate via curves:

Let $z_1,z_2\in D$. Since $D$ is convex, $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow D, t\mapsto z_1+t(z_2-z_1)$ is well defined and smooth. Now FTC implies:

$|f(z_2)-f(z_1)|=|f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))|=|\int_0^1f'(\gamma(s))\gamma '(s)ds|
=|\int_0^1f'(\gamma(s))(z_2-z_1)ds|\leq\int_0^1|f'(\gamma(s))||z_2-z_1|ds
=m|z_2-z_1|.$